# Prevent termination of instance(with container running) in ASG for scale in Event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have AWS infra as ECS + ASG for running container with scale-in protection disabled (to save some amount during night time where less traffic).

Issue i am facing is during scale-in event ECS drained traffic from one container, But ASG terminates instance with container running.

Termination policy does not specify anything which solve this case.

How do i make in-sync such that only that instance get terminated with no container running?

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this case can be handled by enabling managedTerminationProtection option while creating capacity-provider.